# Consequences of cracked metal bumper

Tags: saturn, damage, sl2

I recently rear-ended another car at about 15mph in my 1992 Saturn SL2.

There is some minor damage that I repaired easily: broken plastic on the horn, non-functioning light, cracks in plastic bumper, broken plastic fasteners.

The more substantial damage is a bent radiator (not leaking) and a bent internal metal bumper. The metal bumper behind the plastic and foam was bent enough that it is cracked halfway through.

[image]

Other than providing protection for collisions, it doesn't seem to be a structural part of the chassis. Is it? What are the consequences of leaving this unrepaired, or a simple repair, like a steel plate over the cracked portion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a **structural** part of the vehicle and an **integral part of the collision management**. It's there for your protection and **can significantly change the crash characteristics** of the vehicle causing you or your passengers bodily injury. Also not replacing this can **effect air bag timing**, setting it off on too minor of a collision or not setting it off when it should.

With that being said you should replace it, it may be a bolt on part, if so it's an easy swap and you can get one from a salvage yard or aftermarket collision supplier.

Comment: Thanks. It seems though I was correct in "*Other than providing protection for collisions,* it doesn't seem to be a structural part of the *chassis*." Though I of course understand that collision behavior is no small thing. And FYI, there is no air bag.